# Screenshoting certain part of screen programmatically

Tags: android

In my app I have a rectangle ImageView that contains an white background with a hole cut out from the middle. Behind it I have set a camera preview so only the hole shows the camera. How would I just take a picture of the `IMAGEVIEW.X AND Y AND HEIGHT AND WIDTH` so I can still see the face. Basically crop the screenshot to the size of the imageview
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this Helps.

```
private void takeScreenshot() {
Date now = new Date();
android.text.format.DateFormat.format("yyyy-MM-dd_hh:mm:ss", now);

try {
    // image naming and path  to include sd card  appending name you choose for file
    String mPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/" + now + ".jpg";

    // create bitmap screen capture
    View v1 = getWindow().getDecorView().getRootView();
    v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(v1.getDrawingCache());
    v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);

    File imageFile = new File(mPath);

    FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(imageFile);
    int quality = 100;
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, quality, outputStream);
    outputStream.flush();
    outputStream.close();

    openScreenshot(imageFile);
} catch (Throwable e) {
    // Several error may come out with file handling or OOM
    e.printStackTrace();
 }
}
```